# How to extract Procedure, Function, etc. Source Code from an Oracle Export

Tags: oracle, export, import, source-control

I have generated an `EXPDAT.DMP` file of an Oracle database with the command:

```
exp userid=usr/pass@db owner=own rows=n compress=n
```

I then ran the following command to generate a file containing the 'Create Table...' statements:

```
imp userid=usr/pass@db full=y indexfile=output.sql
```

This is great for the Create Table statements, but I also want the Create Procedure / Create Function / Create View source code. I can see them there in the .DMP file, but I haven't found a way to extract them.

Is it possible to extract this information from the EXPDAT.DMP file? Or will I need to use another method?

The purpose is to have the source exportable to files that can be source-controlled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you've got access to the original database, I'd go with DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL.

You can script it with UTL_FILE so that it goes through each object (from USER_OBJECTS), uses the name and type to extract the object then write it to a file that has the appropriate naming convention.

It will be a lot cleaner than trying to split a single file.

Comment: Can you recommend a good example/tutorial for DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL? I'm mostly finding 'spool... select dbms_metadata.get_dll() from dual; spool off' through Google. Is that about right?

Comment: First place I look for tutorials is oracle-base.com. http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/MetadataAPI.php

Answer (score 3):

Use the [SHOW](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16536/original_import.htm#SUTIL1729) parameter to see the DDL:

```
imp userid=usr/pass@db full=y show=y log=imp.log
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use datapump(expdp,impdp) utility ,instead of traditional export , then sqlfile command can be used.

-- Take expdp

```
 expdp dumpfile=full.dmp logfile=full.log directory=EXP_DIR schemas=SCOTT
```

-- below impdp wont import, it will just generated all the object code in fullcode.sql file

```
impdp dumpfile=full.dmp logfile=full.log directory=EXP_DIR schemas=SCOTT content=metadata_only sqlfile=fullcode.sql
```